# Turn user/item interactions into sparse list removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use transactional data to build a sparse list where each new row consists of a space-delimited list of item ID's for the user, then write the result to a file.
I'm stuck on an efficient way to make unique rows. Here is some sample input:

```
# Make input
d = pd.DataFrame([1,1,2,2,3,4,4], columns=['userID'])
d['itemID'] = [2,3,2,4,1,2,4]
d['code'] = ['AA', 'AA', 'AB', 'AA', 'AB', 'AB', 'AC']
print d

# Group by userID
print d.groupby(by='userID').head()

# Return the country codes
codes = list(d.groupby("userID")["code"].first())

# Grab the list of itemID's for each userID
b = d.groupby("userID")["itemID"].unique()
dd = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['itemID']).reset_index()
dd['code'] = codes # Set the code column
print dd

#print dd.drop_duplicates(cols=["code", "itemID"])
```

That last line (if uncommented) gives the error:

> "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

since the itemID column contains multiple columns.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here's the output from the above code:

```
   userID  itemID code
0       1       2   AA
1       1       3   AA
2       2       2   AB
3       2       4   AA
4       3       1   AB
5       4       2   AB
6       4       4   AC
          userID  itemID code
userID                       
1      0       1       2   AA
       1       1       3   AA
2      2       2       2   AB
       3       2       4   AA
3      4       3       1   AB
4      5       4       2   AB
       6       4       4   AC
   userID  itemID code
0       1  [2, 3]   AA
1       2  [2, 4]   AB
2       3     [1]   AB
3       4  [2, 4]   AB
```

In the final output, I would like to remove index 3, as it is a duplicate of index 1 since the 'itemID' AND 'code' columns are duplicates. I don't care about the userID.

Desired output:

```
   userID  itemID code
0       1  [2, 3]   AA
1       2  [2, 4]   AB
2       3     [1]   AB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a tuple instead of a list.  You need to pass something hashable for the comparison inside of `drop_duplicates` to work:

```
>>> dd = pd.DataFrame(b.map(lambda x: tuple(x)), columns=['itemID']).reset_index()
>>> dd['code'] = codes
>>> dd.drop_duplicates(cols=["code", "itemID"])
   userID  itemID code
0       1  (2, 3)   AA
1       2  (2, 4)   AB
2       3    (1,)   AB
```